# Extracting data from a Web service

Tags: xml, web-services, ssis

I have the IP address, name and port number to connect to a web service and I am able to successfully connect and ping using telnet and command line.

I am looking to extract the data from the webservice using SSIS.

I do not have the URL for he webservice, Is there way to extract the data using the IP address and port number  in order to connect and extract the data?

Really looking forward to suggestions

Thanks!

Comment: Are you downloading an XML file from FTP?

Comment: Are you sure there is a webservice? How can you know? Who told you that? Can the same person give you the URL?

Comment: Yes there is a web service the url is the ipaddress and the port number however the connection times out to get a response